# Android Linear Layout Problem

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

[image]Hi all, 
I'm a newbie to Android and having problems displaying items using a Linear layout and wondering if anyone can help me. The item list and pictures display fine but the textbox and search button are displayed for each item rather than getting displayed once. My code looks like:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/selection"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp" 
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="@string/searchHeader"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchItem"/>
        <Button 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search"
            android:onClick="Search"/>
        </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should go back and accept answers to previous questions first.

Answer (score 3):

With this XML you should only see exactly one imageview and not a list of images as you discribed. Do you alter this layout programmatically in order do display various images? Maybe there you also add again the items you only want once.

Comment: Hi, no i'm only displaying the one image at the moment as i haven't figured out how to dynamically link the images to the text in my XML file yet.

Comment: You can't do dynamical things in a static XML. But you can use list display widgets and use appropriate Adapters to dynamically load their content.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the textview and search button outside of the linearlayouts they are in.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, do you mean moving the textview and buttons completely outside the linear layouts or just the inside one?

Comment: Outside of the inside ones (there's two inside of a third), haha.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Maybe you could post a mock-up image of what you want the layout to look like.

Comment: Good idea, any suggestions on what i can use for mocking up a sample?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve the following: Display an array list from my strings.XML File with an associated image on the right hand side. The array currently holds four or five items.  Under the items i would like to display the text box where users can enter text and a under that again.

Comment: Just draw it in Paint and update your question with the picture.

Comment: Hi Amplify91, just attached a rough mockup above. Thanks for your help